# My POST method can't receive data (flask api)

Tags: python, flask

I'm working on my flask app. I've successfully implemented the rest APIs and now I want to add views to my app. Here is post method:

```
from flask_restful import Resource
from flask import abort, request
from flask_apispec import marshal_with, use_kwargs
from flask_apispec.views import MethodResource

from marshmallow import Schema, fields
from app import api, docs, db
from app.models import Order

class OrderSchema(Schema):
    waiter_name = fields.String()
    table = fields.Integer()
    orders_date = fields.String()
    status_value = fields.String()


class PostOrderSchema(Schema):
    waiter = fields.Integer()
    table = fields.Integer()
    orders_date = fields.String()


class GetOrders(MethodResource, Resource):
    @marshal_with(OrderSchema(many=True))
    def get(self):
        """
            Method which can be used to get all orders

            Expects: nothing
            Modifies: nothing
            Returns: orders
        """

        waiters = get_orders(request.args)

        return waiters

    @use_kwargs(PostOrderSchema, location='json')
    @marshal_with(OrderSchema)
    def post(self, **kwargs):
        """
            Method which can be used to add new orders to the database

            Expects: nothing
            Modifies: nothing
            Returns: created order
        """
        # args = order_put_args.parse_args()
        order = add_to_db(Order, **kwargs)

        return order


api.add_resource(GetOrder, '/json_orders/<int:id>')
api.add_resource(GetOrders, '/json_orders')

docs.register(GetOrder)
docs.register(GetOrders)
```

Here is my views:

```
import requests
from flask import render_template, redirect, url_for
from flask.views import MethodView

from app import app, db
from app.views.form import AddEditOrderForm
from app.models import Waiter, Status


BASE = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/'


# Add Views
class ControlOrderView(MethodView):
    def get(self):
        return render_template('add_edit_forms/add-edit_order.html', **self.prepare_context())

    def post(self):
        form = AddEditOrderForm()

        if form.validate_on_submit():
            requests.post(BASE + 'json_orders', data={
                'waiter': 1, # form.waiter.data.split()[0],
                'orders_date': "2023-01-02", # form.orders_date.data,
                # 'status': '1', form.status.data.split()[0],
                'table': '3' # form.table.data
            })

        return redirect(url_for('get_all_orders'))

    def prepare_context(self):
        form = AddEditOrderForm()

        waiters = Waiter.query.all()
        form.waiter.choices = list(
            f'{waiter.first_name} {waiter.last_name}' for waiter in waiters
        )

        statuses = Status.query.all()
        form.status.choices = list(
            f'{status.id} - {status.status}' for status in statuses
        )

        title = 'ADD ORDER'
        submit_url = '/add-order'
        cancel_button = 'get_all_orders'

        return {
            'title': title,
            'form': form,
            'submit_url': submit_url,
            'cancel_button': cancel_button
        }


app.add_url_rule('/add-order', view_func=ControlOrderView.as_view('add_order'), methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

With GET request everything is fine, But POST request gives such errors:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb.OperationalError) (1048, "Column 'waiter' cannot be null")
[SQL: INSERT INTO orders (waiter, `table`) VALUES (%s, %s)]
[parameters: (None, None)]
```

It seems the API can't receive the data. I was trying to debug it and found out that `**kwargs` is an empty dictionary

UPDATE

Here is implementation of `add_to_db` function:

```
def add_to_db(cls, **kwargs):
    obj = cls()
    for atr, value in kwargs.items():
        setattr(obj, atr, value)

    db.session.add(obj)
    db.session.commit()

    return obj
```

Comment: Does that error come from this code, or from the api being called by `requests.post`?

Comment: Also, `form = AddEditOrderForm()` creates an empty form.  It doesn't look like you're actually filling in that form with whatever information the user entered.

Comment: I'm not sure, but an error occurs at the line `order = add_to_db(Order, **kwargs)` because there is no data at `**kwargs` variable

Comment: The `add_to_db()` function is not defined anywhere that I can see.  Not sure how this code would even run...

Comment: I do fill the form, but I've hardcoded `data` value to exclude that the form may be the cause of the error

Comment: It works fine when i send requests via Postman or Swager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've changed this:

```
requests.post(BASE + 'json_orders', data={
                'waiter': 1, # form.waiter.data.split()[0],
                'orders_date': "2023-01-02", # form.orders_date.data,
                # 'status': '1', form.status.data.split()[0],
                'table': '3' # form.table.data
            })
```

to this

```
requests.post(BASE + 'json_orders', json={
                'waiter': 1, # form.waiter.data.split()[0],
                'orders_date': "2023-01-02", # form.orders_date.data,
                # 'status': '1', form.status.data.split()[0],
                'table': '3' # form.table.data
            })
```

And now everything is working

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).